# Is there any way to use application.yml outside the project resources in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have spring boot project. It's working fine when I use application.yml in resources directory.
I'm trying to move out application.yml outside resources directory, But It doesn't work anymore.
It's my curious just want to know, Is there any way to make it works?

Comment: outside resource directory, in same project?

Comment: Yes, It's in the same project.

Comment: Why do you want to move it outside the resources directory?

Comment: [spring-boot - how to specify path of application.properties in envrionment or system properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804646/spring-boot-how-to-specify-path-of-application-properties-in-envrionment-or-sy)

Comment: [How to specify an external application.yml in spring with profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385456/how-to-specify-an-external-application-yml-in-spring-with-profiles?rq=1)

Comment: It's my curious. I just want to move application.yml to outside resource to other directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can point to your alternative path using the environment property `spring.config.location`, e.g. by starting your application as follows:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=/some/path/application.yml
```

Please also review [section "External Application Properties" in the official Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files).

Answer (score 0):

You can use @PropertySource annotation to load from any location

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {

// more configuration ...
}
```

// add path to application.yml